# Boosting Span Near

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elastic search and trying to use a span_near with fuzzy matching. It's working well with the query below. However, I'd like to boost the span_near matche. I know I can boost the fuzzy queries individually. However, is it possible to boost the entire span_near? Is this possible or should I be doing something else?

```
{
  "span_near": {
    "clauses": [
      {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "container": {
                "fuzziness": "1",
                "value": "foo"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "container": {
                "fuzziness": "2",
                "value": "bar"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "slop": 20,
    "in_order": true
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a boost for the entire *span_near* query using the boost option.

Example:

```
{
  "span_near": {
    "clauses": [
      {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "container": {
                "fuzziness": "1",
                "value": "foo"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "span_multi": {
          "match": {
            "fuzzy": {
              "container": {
                "fuzziness": "2",
                "value": "bar"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "slop": 20,
    "in_order": true,
    "boost" : 20
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct! Thanks. The issue I had was actually using the elasticserarch.net and NEST. NEST doesn't support boost here. I just submitted a pull request with the suggested update.